# Joining on a many to many relationship with LINQ

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework, ef-database-first

I have been tasked with converting some old SQL stored procs to LINQ for an EF migration we are doing and Im a little stumped. Given that this is a migration from an existing application the edmx was generated database first. So, I have a SQL statement that I am trying to replicate:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    d.DeliverySubscriptionId
,   d.ContactId
,   d.statementMacroId_fk
,   m.Name as MacroName
,   DeliveryMethod  =     REPLACE((SELECT DISTINCT
                                    dm2.Name + ',' AS 'data()'
                              FROM
                                    DeliverySubscription d2     
                              JOIN 
                                    StatementMacro m2 on 
                                    d2.StatementMacroId_fk = m2.StatementMacroId    
                              JOIN 
                                    DeliverySubscription_Method_Rel dmr2 ON 
                                    d2.DeliverySubscriptionId = dmr2.DeliverySubscriptionId_Fk
                              JOIN 
                                    dbo.DeliveryMethod dm2 ON 
                                    dmr2.DeliveryMethodId_Fk = dm2.DeliveryMethodId
                              WHERE
                                    d.DeliveryConfigurationId_fk = @configurationId
                                    AND 
                                    d.IsActive = 1
                                    AND
                                    D.DeliverySubscriptionId = D2.DeliverySubscriptionId FOR XML PATH('')) + '$', ',$', '') 

FROM 
      DeliverySubscription d     
INNER JOIN 
      StatementMacro m ON 
      d.StatementMacroId_fk = m.StatementMacroId    
JOIN 
      DeliverySubscription_Method_Rel dmr ON 
      d.DeliverySubscriptionId = dmr.DeliverySubscriptionId_Fk
JOIN dbo.DeliveryMethod dm ON 
      dmr.DeliveryMethodId_Fk = dm.DeliveryMethodId
WHERE 
      d.DeliveryConfigurationId_fk = @configurationId
      AND 
      d.IsActive = 1
```

In particular the part that I have having an issue with is the JOIN `DeliverySubscription_Method_Rel` which is a relationship table representing a many to many relationship between `DeliverySubscription` and `DeliveryMethod`.

This shows up as:

`[DeliverySubscription] * ---- * [Delivery Method]`

in the database diagram in the edmx. No `DeliverySubscription_Method_Rel` entity is created. As you can see in the SQL statement the JOIN is directly on the relationship table, but I cant seem to figure out how to replicate this in LINQ. Please help!

UPDATE:
So looking around the web I found a similar example which suggested doing something like this:

```
from s in Context.DeliverySubscriptions
                from dm in s.DeliveryMethods
                join sm in Context.StatementMacroes on s.StatementMacroId_Fk equals sm.StatementMacroId
                where s.DeliveryConfigurationId_Fk == configurationId
                select new DeliverySubscription_dto
                {
                    DeliverySubscriptionId = s.DeliverySubscriptionId,
                    QubeContactId = s.QubeContactId,
                    statementMacroId_fk = s.StatementMacroId_Fk,
                    MacroName = sm.Name,
                    DeliveryMethod = dm.Name.Replace("$","").Replace(",$","")
                }
```

...however because I still have a lot of other things to change in the application thus far I am unable to build in order to test this yet so I just wanted to run this buy you all to see if this seems correct.

Comment: try **[sqltolinq](http://www.sqltolinq.com/)** for complex queries.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, thats a nifty little program. Unfortunately it seems unable to convert this SQL statement. I keep getting "Index was outside the bounds of the array."

Answer (score 0):

That query is a beast. If you weren't having any performance problems with it, I would probably just add it to the datamodel and use linq/EF to call it.